# Pythonic style for checking result of system calls

Tags: python, system, popen

I have inherited a python script that is essentially a shell script, it uses repeated calls to `os.system()` to run a bunch of command line utilities without necessarily checking the result. In order to make the script a little more rugged, I was thinking of adding class methods like below:

```
    def subprocess(self, cmd):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        while proc.poll() is None:
            if proc.wait() == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def check_package_installed(self, pkg):
       cmd = " ".join(["dnf list installed", pkg])
       rv = self.subprocess(cmd)
       if rv != True:
          raise Exception("Package {} not installed.".format(pkg)))
```

And then, in the main section of the script, something like this:

```
try:
    checker.check_package_installed("jdkasjdsa")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ",e)
    # recovery code here
```

Is this the kind of idiomatic code another Python programmer would expect for this task?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense, why `while proc.poll() is None: ...`? But then you immediately doan `if proc.wait() == 0: ...`? Why not just `proc.wait()` without the while loop?

Comment: In any case, this is all re-inventing the wheel, you just want to use `subprocess.run` which will block until the process completes and return a `CompletedProcess` object with an error code, althernatively, pass `subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True)` it and will raise an Exception o

Answer (score 0):

My answer was on similar lines as @juanpa.arrivillaga comment. Instead of using Popen you can use subprocess.run command using the below example. The subprocess.run will wait for the command to complete and it will return a CompletedProcess instance. If you dont care output you can use pass check=True and it will raise subprocess.CalledProcessError exception if the command returns error code !=0.

```
import subprocess
class CheckProcess:

    def execute_cmd(self, cmd):
        result = False
        try:
            output = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True)
            result = True
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
            print('Exception hit: %s', exc)
        else:
            return result

    def check_package_installed(self, pkg):
       cmd = " ".join(["dnf list installed", pkg])
       result = self.execute_cmd(cmd)
       if result != True:
          raise Exception("Package {} not installed.".format(pkg))

c = CheckProcess()
c.check_package_installed('cchfhfjgj')
```

Output

```
Exception hit: %s Command 'dnf list installed cchfhfjgj' returned non-zero exit status 127.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-2-029eeeb6eef7> in <module>()
     19 
     20 c = CheckProcess()
---> 21 c.check_package_installed('cchfhfjgj')

<ipython-input-2-029eeeb6eef7> in check_package_installed(self, pkg)
     16        rv = self.subprocess(cmd)
     17        if rv != True:
---> 18           raise Exception("Package {} not installed.".format(pkg))
     19 
     20 c = CheckProcess()

Exception: Package cchfhfjgj not installed.
```

Please read the subprocess.run documentation specific to Python version that you are using on your system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using of `Exception` is little bit wide.

   Let's suppose that your `pkg` will be integer. Then `join` operation will be failed with `TypeError`. However `TypeError` is subclass for `Exception` and that means that you will try to run `recovery code here` even if different `Exception` raised
2. Looks like you creating script for internal usage and that is not a big problem, but generally arguments passed to command should be escaped
3. Your command result check logic is awkward and fragile (most important problem)

You may try this code:

```py
import subprocess
import shlex


# this Exception class allows us to except exact Exceptions only
class PackageNotFoundException(OSError):
  pass


class UnexpectedException(OSError):
  pass


class Checker:

  # using static method we able to run this method without creating instance
  @staticmethod
  def check_package(pkg_name: str):
    # shlex.quote(pkg_name) -> escape command line parameter
    result = subprocess.Popen(
      "/usr/bin/env dnf list installed " + shlex.quote(pkg_name),
      shell=True,
      # hide output
      stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
      stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )

    _, err = result.communicate()
    err = err.decode('utf8').rstrip('\r\n')
    exit_code = result.wait()

    # check exact error (dnf returns 1 if package not found)
    if exit_code == 1 and 'No matching Packages' in err:
      raise PackageNotFoundException(f"Package not found {pkg_name}")
    # if command status code is not 0
    if exit_code != 0:
      raise UnexpectedException(f"Error [{err}] with status code {exit_code} happens when trying to check {pkg_name}")

package = "package name with spaces"

try:
  Checker.check_package(package)
# handle package not found error
except PackageNotFoundException as e:
  print(f"Trying to install package {package}")
  # recovery code here
# re-raise error if unknown (unexpected) error
except Exception as e:
  raise e
```